# Why is this ground-like current zero?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I'm simply confused on why \$ i_x= 0 \$

[image]

Comment: A current flows from one circuit node to another, but the dots on either side of the \$i_x\$ arrow are the same node (b).

Comment: If there were current, what would cause it, where would come from and why?

Comment: @Justme i personnally think that \$ i_x = i \$ and not 0 , but after that i saw the direction of flow of the current 20i i think that i and 20i would clash, im honestly so confused in that kind of situation where two currents come from two sides like two sources generating current, how do we apply the LKC

Comment: @Null I would hope that a diamond mod should refrain from answering OPs question in the comment section.

Comment: Simplistically, current must flow in a loop - it has to return back to the source which "created" it. How would any non-zero current ix return back where it cam from?

Comment: @Null Current can flow within a node. It's voltage that you can't have within a node. Otherwise you could break Kirchoff's current law by just extending a node.

Comment: @Hearth i dont really understand your answer please explain more, i know that current splits when facing a current, but from what i've heard it only splits if the sub-path in which the current splitted into trace back to the main loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the lumped element model of a circuit, current entering/exiting a node must sum to zero (KCL), and likewise current entering/exiting a subgraph of the circuit must also sum to zero.

If a non-zero current i_x were flowing from the left subgraph (circled below) to the right subgraph of the circuit, it would have no way to return into that subgraph.

[image]

Addressing a comment:

> i think that i and 20i would clash

They do not. If you split up the bottom node and wrote KCL out, you'd find that the current 20i circulates in the 20i controlled current source, 25-ohm resistor, and in whatever circuit is attached across the a-b port. The current i circulates in the voltage source, 2k resistor, and 3v controlled voltage source.

Comment: ha you see! why wouldnt they clash? arent they dependent sources? can you pleaaaase write the KCL for the parts you circled ?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI They are dependent sources, but I do not see why they would clash. If I start writing equations, I can create *interdependent* equations, but I can't think of a way to create a *contradictory* equation.

Comment: so what i've concluded from the second paragraph you wrote , the only way a current is non-zero & the requirement to apply kirchoff current law is that the entering current must return at some point in the given circuit otherwise the current is not exiting?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI I'm not 100% sure I understood your sentence fully, but yes, if current leaves the  left subcircuit and enters the right subcircuit, it needs a path to get back into the left subcircuit. And there is none here.

Answer (score 0):

Current only flows in closed loops, and there is no closed loop that contains the ix wire. No current can flow that way.

Perhaps the diagram is drawn suggestively to human eyes, but electrons don't care what the diagram looks like, only whether they have a loop to flow along.

If you can describe what you thought might happen, it would be easier to understand what confuses you. To my (embattled) eyes, it's very difficult to see what you see that is confusing.

Comment: so the i_x current runs in a single wire which doesnt form a loop?

Comment: It doesn't. There is no current in that wire because it is not part of any loop. The notation in your question, "ix=0" says exactly that. Any number other than zero would mean some current flows, but the number 0 means "no current".

Comment: how do you determine if there is a loop or no?

Comment: by inspection..

Comment: How do you define a loop in a circuit?

Comment: @MOHAMEDSALHI [Here is a detailed definition](https://chat.openai.com/share/f87d4503-b181-4876-8c26-b8124f6439e3), which you can interrogate for further clarification, as needed.